# error while setting image in imageView in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I have written a code for setting imageview ...as per the button clicked...but my problem is when i press the button it is giving me the error like...too many arguments to function ImageNamed...while executing this line...

`UIImage* photo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"robort %d.jpg",x];`

the whole code is....

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
NSLog(@"%d",button.tag);
int x;
x=button.tag;
// Create the image view.
UIImage* photo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"robort %d.jpg",x];
NSLog(@"%d",x);
CGSize photoSize = [photo size];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, photoSize.width, photoSize.height)];
[imageView setImage:photo];
[self.view addSubview:imageView]; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `UIImage* photo = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"robort de nero%d.jpg",x]];`

cheers :)

Comment: :) it's usual that we miss such small things

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
NSLog(@"%d",button.tag);
int x;
x=button.tag;
// Create the image view.
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"robort %d.jpg",x];
UIImage* photo = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
NSLog(@"%d",x);
CGSize photoSize = [photo size];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, photoSize.width, photoSize.height)];
[imageView setImage:photo];
[self.view addSubview:imageView]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
UIImage* photo = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"robort %d.jpg",x]];
```

Comment: yup it is the way...Thanks..UP...:)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
UIImage* photo = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"robort %d.jpg",x]];
```